# Autorun.inf don't work and I can't run c# exe

Tags: c#, usb, exe, autorun

I am Adel and I am creating an program and I want to save it into an USB and auto run it whenever the USB is inserted to any Windows device, the problem is that the code that I use in Autorun.inf doesn't work.
The files in the correct path and the Autorun.inf file in the root of the USB, but it's not working!
NOTE: the exe also works

The code:

```
[Autorun]
Icon=USBSYS\icon.ico
open=USBSYS\file.exe
action=MyUSBName
Label=MyUSBName
```

Comment: There are utilities you can install on your PC that will scan mounted drives for autorun files and run them if that is what you want.

Comment: FYI, you are not *Adel*. You are *Mhmd idk*. It says so in the lower right corner of your question and in [your site profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12082020/mhmd-idk), and will say so on every question, answer and comment you post here, because it's the name you gave your account. If you want to be *Adel*, then you can change your account name to use that instead.

Comment: As far as your question goes, WIndows disabled autorun on USB drives several years ago as an anti-malware measure, so you are never going to get it to work unless you're happy with running on Windows 95 and earlier versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Autorun.inf does not work anymore on USB drives.  Its a security thing to prevent people from putting malicious programs on a thumb drive.  It does work on CDs/DVDs though.